# function that takes an array and arguments separated by commas and returns a function that returns any number

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please, help. I need to write the function that takes an array of numbers and returns a function that, when called, returns any number from this array passed to it, and also, that you can pass the range not only through the array, but as arguments separated by commas.

```js
function makeRandom(arg) {
    if(arg.constructor === Array) {
        return function() {
            return arg[Math.floor(Math.random() * arg.length)]
        }
    } else {
        return function() {
            let args = Array(arg);
            return args[Math.floor(Math.random() * args.length)]
        }
    }
};
const getRandomNumber = makeRandom([1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33])
console.log(getRandomNumber()) // 556
console.log(getRandomNumber()) // 100

const getRandomNumberTwo = makeRandom(1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33)
console.log(getRandomNumberTwo()) // undefined
console.log(getRandomNumberTwo()) // undefined
```

With array it works, but with arguments it produces undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) of the function, if no array is handed over.

```js
function makeRandom(arg) {
    if (arg.constructor !== Array) {
        arg = Array.from(arguments);
    }
    return function() {
        return arg[Math.floor(Math.random() * arg.length)];
    };
}
const getRandomNumber = makeRandom([1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33])
console.log(getRandomNumber()) // 556
console.log(getRandomNumber()) // 100

const getRandomNumberTwo = makeRandom(1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33)
console.log(getRandomNumberTwo());
console.log(getRandomNumberTwo());
```

Comment: it doesn't work. getRandomNumberTwo will be undefined too

Comment: yes, on the example code after getRandomNumberTwo, there is incorrect console.log

Comment: @ameli, sorry. now it shoulf work by setting `arg` to an array. The reason, why it did not work, was the returning function has an own `argument`, and the outer is never used.

Answer (score 2):

Use rest operator for this.

```
function makeRandom(...arg) {
    if(arg.constructor === Array) {
        return function() {
            return arg[Math.floor(Math.random() * arg.length)]
        }
    } else {
        return function() {
            let args = Array(arg);
            return args[Math.floor(Math.random() * args.length)]
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: `...` when used in context of function parameter list, it is known as `rest` parameter syntax, not `spread` syntax

Comment: it not works with array. the output is
const getRandomNumber = makeRandom([1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33])
console.log(getRandomNumber()) // [1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33]
console.log(getRandomNumber()) // [1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33]

const getRandomNumberTwo = makeRandom(1, 2, 100, 34, 45, 556, 33)
console.log(getRandomNumberTwo()) // 2
console.log(getRandomNumberTwo())  //100